# Ownership issues with SSRS subscriptions to sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2007

### Programs used

- SSRS 2008 R2
- Sharepoint 2007

So here's the issue my co-worker and I are facing. We have subscription for a report going to a Sharepoint library. We're currently using "Windows File Share" as the delivery method, as we have no other options available.

What we're finding is that the file is being pushed successfully, but it's not being "checked in" so that it's available to viewing by all people in the library.

Barring doing what's suggested here: [SSRS in Sharepoint Integrated mode](http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/06/01/how-to-setup-ssrs-in-sharepoint-integrated-mode/)
Is there anyway to make this work? One idea that cropped up was putting the subscription to a share on the SSRS server, then pushing via a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way, assuming you have access to customize your SharePoint system, would be to add an [event receiver on the ItemAdded event](http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/walkthroughs/event-receivers-walkthrough2/) of the document library. This will fire whenever a document is added to the library. Within the event receiver check that the item is being added by the account used by your Reporting Services system and check it in (because you don't want to automatically check in everyone's documents when they are added, just the reports).

Alternatively, you could do the same thing using a [workflow](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-workflows-HA010154424.aspx).